# Android - layout directory in large density (2.25)

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, screen-density

I have a strange bug on Samsung Galaxy Tab E (Nougat 7.0 API 24): I have 2 layout directory (layout and layout-sw600dp) when I change the "Screen Zoom" on the "Settings" to "Huge" the device for some reason is taking the XML from the "layout" directory and not from the "layout-sw600dp", for all the others density it works perfectly except the this one.

Is there a solution for this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only in Galaxy devices but you can have this in any device exceeding the **sw** system.

So instead of making specific folders like `layout-sw600` etc, I recommend you to make specific layouts using ConstraintLayout.

ConstraintLayout not only makes your layout flexible but also adjusts it's size based on the increase or decrease in **Density Pixels** of the devices and also saves your. Development Time. I faced a similar issue long time back and decided to use ConstraintLayout for the same.

A good codelab from Google on ConstraintLayout can be found here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018#0

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The system will use the one which is closest to (**without exceeding**) the device's smallestWidth, but when Screen Zoom set to Huge, the smallest width of device **exceeds** 600dp.

And your layout files only have two folders (`layout` and `layout-sw600dp`), so finally the system choose the `layout` folder.

Comment: and before the zoom, the smallest width of the device was not exceeded 600dp? it is a device with a resolution of 1200X1920.